# In Android 4.2.2 Multiuser profile the apps are installed for each user or they just create the new instance?

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I am just trying to understand the Android 4.2.2, the apps are installed for each user or these apps are just creating a new instances for the new profile users.

Whenever I create the new profile user in Jellybean supported Tablet some apps are already there like gmail, youtube, maps etc. what it means? Are they installed once again or create the instance from owner installed apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual apk file is only installed once, and is common to all users.

However, each user profile reports a separate physical location on the storage disks for the app's internal and external memory, so the app's data is unique to each user.

This way, each user gets a complete installation of the app, without requiring multiple copies to exist.

Comment: thanks Raghav for speedy response but can i get more reference... regarding this..